# Apache : one of my RewriteRules doesn't working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

All of my RewriteRules runs fine except one: `^assets/(.*)$ site/assets/$1 [L]`

Actually with this one I get a 404 error but my file is at the good place...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js" ></script>
```

File in `MAMP/website_name/site/assets/js/script.js`

I tried different methods but nothing solve the problem.

The `RewriteRule ^js/(.*) site/webroot/js/$1 [L]` works well !

Here's my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ site/assets/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule fileXupload/server/php/$ fileXupload/server/php/index.php [L]
  RewriteRule site/webroot/uploads$ http://signatix.local [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule site/webroot/uploads/$ http://signatix.local [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule fckeditor/(.*) externallibs/fckeditor/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^img/(.*) site/webroot/img/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^imgupload/(.*) site/webroot/imgupload/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^js/(.*) site/webroot/js/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^css/(.*) site/webroot/css/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^upload/(.*) site/webroot/upload/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^/img/(.*) site/webroot/img/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule /upload/(.*) site/webroot/upload/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule /upload.php site/upload.php [L]
  RewriteRule /md5.php site/md5.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*) site/webroot/uploads/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)([[:punct:]]?)(.+)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

  #RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !on
  #RewriteRule (.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I'm trying to get all of my RewriteRules working.

Comment: does it help if you remove the leading `^`?

Comment: No... I tried different methods...

Comment: Add `LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6` to your virtualhost .conf and reload apache, then you will have very detailed rewrite logs so you can see what is actually happening